# Visual Studio 2012 "Source not Available" "Code not Running" while debugging Win Form Apps

Tags: debugging

When I attempt to debug win forms apps, when the debugger hits the breakpoint I get the message "Source not Available" and "Code not running" and if I push F11 the app keeps on running. The weird thing, Console apps seem to debug fine. I tried resetting the setting and the like, none of which seemed to help. I can recreate the problem by creating an empty Win Forms app and putting a single line in the Load method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What breakpoint? What's the stack trace?  Are you clicking Pause?

Comment: Breakpoint is set in the Load method on the only line on the method (Console.WriteLine("Test")) and no, I am no clicking pause.

Comment: Build => Rebuild Solution. Check Tools => Options => Debugging. It's doubtful it's these settings, but there's stuff like "Just My Code" and "Enable .NET Source Stepping" that can change your debugging experience.

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried all that with no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem and I'm posting this for other who may have the same issue. The problem was related to Telerik JustMock installation on my machine. Apparently their 2013 Q3 release had issues. Uninstalling it or updating to the latest version did the trick.

[ASP.NET MVC5/IIS Express unable to debug - Code Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472682/asp-net-mvc5-iis-express-unable-to-debug-code-not-running)

http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/105/Feedback/Details/63749-unable-to-debug-asp-net-projects-with-q3-2013